# Wicket Bootstrap MaterialDesignTheme not selected?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wicket, material-design

I must be missing somethins simple, but I have a hard time getting the MaterialDesignTheme getting used in my minimal WicketApplication.

This is what I do:

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication
{

    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage()
    {
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        super.init();
        Bootstrap.install(this);

        BootstrapSettings settings = new BootstrapSettings();
        settings.setThemeProvider(new SingleThemeProvider(new MaterialDesignTheme()));
        Bootstrap.install(this, settings);

        // add your configuration here
        System.out.println(settings.getThemeProvider().available());
    }
}
```

I see the Theme in the syso.

Then, in my HomePage:

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        IBootstrapSettings settings = Bootstrap.getSettings(Application.get());

        settings.getActiveThemeProvider().setActiveTheme(new MaterialDesignTheme());

        add(new Heading("version", getApplication().getFrameworkSettings().getVersion()));

        Form f = new BootstrapForm<Void>("f") {

        };

        f.add(new TextField<String>("text", Model.of("aap")));
        add(f);
    }

    public void renderHead(final IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);
        Bootstrap.renderHead(response);
    }
}
```

I don't see any material design CSS or JS in the rendered head..

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is really silly, but I added the `Bootstrap.install(this);` twice. This seems to mess up things.